# Why is my tracking link Source/Medium showing as EmailCampaign/email

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, utm

I have been tracking links coming from emails that could possibly land on our main website first and then on Eventbrite. We have set up cross-domain tracking and all of our links are UTM tagged.

Google Analytics, under the Acquisition, Source/Medium report, is showing "emailCampaign/email" instead of our source and medium utm tags (emh / em1).

The strange thing is that if I look up the Behaviour/Landing Pages report, then I can see the URL with emh/em1 but it’s got hardly any conversions at all because most of them are credited to emailCampaign/email in the Acquisition report.

Here’s an example of what my utm tagged URL would look like: https://example.com/?reference=em1&utm_source=emh&utm_medium=em1&utm_campaign=2020examplecampaign

I wonder if anyone can help with this?

Thank you

Comment: Show me one of this URL, pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a redirect or the URL text is what you see but the actual link has unwanted UTMs.

Comment: Hi Michele, what do you mean exactly about unwanted UTMs? Isn’t the UTM formula there correct?

Comment: I mean that should be the text of URL is correct but the link is another. It is only a possibility not necessary the real situation. However the behavior is very strange, it would be better to see it directly.

Comment: Hi Michele, I just wanted to let you know that I have actually figured it out. It was the EMS’s fault. For some reason in test mode it looks ok, but then when the email gets sent out it overrides the source and medium parameters I set up and it replaces it with a default emailCampaign / email. So I will have to investigate with them why this happens. Thank you for all your help.